# Explain how RAM is modified by ArrayList vs LinkedList and identify big-O costs

Tags: javascript, java, arraylist

Consider the following class definition (see attached file), consisting of a main() method and a promote() method that promotes a specified item to the front of a list.

2) Examine each line of the promote() method (i.e., LINE 1 and LINE 2) when invoked with an ArrayList.
          a) Explain what the statement accomplishes.
          b) Describe how RAM is modified by each statement.
          c) Identify the Big-O cost for each statement.

3) Examine each line of the promote() method (i.e., LINE 1 and LINE 2) when invoked with an LinkedList.
          a) Explain what the statement accomplishes.
          b) Describe how RAM is modified by each statement.
          c) Identify the Big-O cost for each statement.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

class Week2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         List<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
         List<String> linked = new LinkedList<>();

         for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'm'; c++) {
             String s = "" + c;
             array.add(s);
             linked.add(s);
         }

         // ARRAY-BASED LIST
         // array = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m]
         promote(array, 3);
         System.out.println(array);  // prints: = [d, a, b, c, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m]

         // LINKED LIST
         // linked = [a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m]
         promote(linked, 3);
         System.out.println(linked); // prints: = [d, a, b, c, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m]
    }

    /*  PRECONDITION: list is a non-empty list; 0 <= a < list.size()
     * POSTCONDITION: Moves the ith element to the front of the list.
     */
    private static void promote(List<String> list, int i) {
        String item = list.remove(i);    // LINE 1
        list.add(0, item);               // LINE 2
    }
}
```

Comment: And what would you learn if we did your homework?

Comment: Look at this article (https://beginnersbook.com/2013/12/difference-between-arraylist-and-linkedlist-in-java/) and at least try to figure this stuff out yourself.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because IT'S HOMEWORK!

Comment: Look, I get that it's homework, but could you at least link me any resources that could help me figure this out. I've tried watching all the YT vids but they mostly cover insertion/deletion differences of ArrayList vs LinkedList but this question pertains to searching/moving elements.

Comment: Moving is deletion plus insertion. That’s even how `promote` is implemented: line 1 is a deletion, line 2 is an insertion.